# How to use TFS in SharePoint2010

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, tfs

Our team is going to start a new project on SharePoint 2010. Can any one tell me how to implement Team Foundation Server(TFS) in SharePoint 2010.

Comment: James i got started with that just few days ago.Withe TFS VS 2010 is very well  integrated.So if you have VS 2010 then you are ready to go.

Answer (score 3):

In SharePoint 2010 development, TFS can be used just like the same way you use it other Visual Studio 2010 projects. 
In VS2010, you got templates that are specifically created for building SharePoint solutions. You choose from those templates to build SharePoint artifacts. Once you have identified your template to use, go ahead and create your team project and bind it to source control.

Hope this helps.